# Error in function to return 3 largest values from a list of numbers

Tags: python, numbers, max

I have this data file and I have to find the 3 largest numbers it contains

```
24.7    25.7    30.6    47.5    62.9    68.5    73.7    67.9    61.1    48.5    39.6    20.0
16.1    19.1    24.2    45.4    61.3    66.5    72.1    68.4    60.2    50.9    37.4    31.1
10.4    21.6    37.4    44.7    53.2    68.0    73.7    68.2    60.7    50.2    37.2    24.6
21.5    14.7    35.0    48.3    54.0    68.2    69.6    65.7    60.8    49.1    33.2    26.0
19.1    20.6    40.2    50.0    55.3    67.7    70.7    70.3    60.6    50.7    35.8    20.7
14.0    24.1    29.4    46.6    58.6    62.2    72.1    71.7    61.9    47.6    34.2    20.4
8.4     19.0    31.4    48.7    61.6    68.1    72.2    70.6    62.5    52.7    36.7    23.8
11.2    20.0    29.6    47.7    55.8    73.2    68.0    67.1    64.9    57.1    37.6    27.7
13.4    17.2    30.8    43.7    62.3    66.4    70.2    71.6    62.1    46.0    32.7    17.3
22.5    25.7    42.3    45.2    55.5    68.9    72.3    72.3    62.5    55.6    38.0    20.4
17.6    20.5    34.2    49.2    54.8    63.8    74.0    67.1    57.7    50.8    36.8    25.5
20.4    19.6    24.6    41.3    61.8    68.5    72.0    71.1    57.3    52.5    40.6    26.2
```

Therefore I have written the following code, but it only searches the first row of numbers instead of the entire list. Can anyone help to find the error?

```
def three_highest_temps(f):
    file = open(f, "r")
    largest = 0
    second_largest = 0
    third_largest = 0
    temp = []
    for line in file:
        temps = line.split()

        for i in temps:
            if i > largest:
                largest = i
            elif largest > i > second_largest:
                second_largest = i
            elif second_largest > i > third_largest:
                third_largest = i
        return largest, second_largest, third_largest

print(three_highest_temps("data5.txt"))
```

Comment: Those don't look like integers to me.

Comment: You should initialize the values with `float('-inf')`. Otherwise you might run into problems when one day the largest value is negative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `return` statement is inside the `for` loop. Once return is reached, the function terminates, so the loop never gets into a second iteration. Move the `return` outside the loop by reducing indentation.

```
    for line in file:
        temps = line.split()

        for i in temps:
            if i > largest:
                largest = i
            elif largest > i > second_largest:
                second_largest = i
            elif second_largest > i > third_largest:
                third_largest = i
    return largest, second_largest, third_largest
```

In addition, your comparisons won't work, because `line.split()` returns a list of strings, not floats. (As has been pointed out, your data consists of floats, not ints. I'm assuming the task is to find the largest float.) So let's convert the strings using `float()`

Your code still won't be correct, though, because when you find a new largest value, you completely discard the old one. Instead you should now consider it the second largest known value. Same rule applies for second to third largest.

```
    for line in file:
        temps = line.split()

        for temp_string in temps:
            i = float(temp_string)
            if i > largest:
                third_largest = second_largest
                second_largest = largest
                largest = i
            elif largest > i > second_largest:
                third_largest = second_largest
                second_largest = i
            elif second_largest > i > third_largest:
                third_largest = i
    return largest, second_largest, third_largest
```

Now there is one last issue:

You overlook cases where i is identical with one of the largest values. In such a case `i > largest` would be false, but so would `largest > i`. You could change either of these comparisons to `>=` to fix this.

Instead, let us simplify the `if` clauses by considering that the `elif` conditions are only considered after all previous conditions were already found to be false. When we reach the first `elif`, we already know that `i` can not be larger than `largest`, so it suffices to compare it to `second largest`. The same goes for the second `elif`.

```
    for line in file:
        temps = line.split()

        for temp_string in temps:
            i = float(temp_string)
            if i > largest:
                third_largest = second_largest
                second_largest = largest
                largest = i
            elif i > second_largest:
                third_largest = second_largest
                second_largest = i
            elif i > third_largest:
                third_largest = i
    return largest, second_largest, third_largest
```

This way we avoid accidentally filtering out the `i == largest` and `i == second_largest` edge cases.

Comment: this returns (8.2, 73.0, 72.7) for some reason basically for i in temps: it is the columns split of the data but it doesn't check all

Comment: You are comparing strings at the moment. You have to convert `i` into a float

Comment: how would i do that when I use [float(i) for i in temps]: it throws everything off

Comment: what do you mean by "throws everything off"? See my updated answer for a code example.

Comment: well the return is just printing out (0,0,0) not the desire out put Im not sure what is going wrong ill try running it thru visualizer

Comment: can you provide the new code? `temps = [float(i) for i in temps]` should work, so your problem probably lies at a different point. To debug, just add a few print statements. For example print `i` and the three `largest` variables within the first if statement to see whether it is ever reached.

Comment: i edited it in the comments not sure why it is not working for the data file . the print statments are returning (0,0,0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97871/discussion-between-marc-schulder-and-sinoda).

Answer (score 12):

Your data contains `float` numbers not `integer`.

You can use `sorted`:

```
>>> data = '''24.7    25.7    30.6    47.5    62.9    68.5    73.7    67.9    61.1    48.5    39.6    20.0
... 16.1    19.1    24.2    45.4    61.3    66.5    72.1    68.4    60.2    50.9    37.4    31.1
... 10.4    21.6    37.4    44.7    53.2    68.0    73.7    68.2    60.7    50.2    37.2    24.6
... 21.5    14.7    35.0    48.3    54.0    68.2    69.6    65.7    60.8    49.1    33.2    26.0
... 19.1    20.6    40.2    50.0    55.3    67.7    70.7    70.3    60.6    50.7    35.8    20.7
... 14.0    24.1    29.4    46.6    58.6    62.2    72.1    71.7    61.9    47.6    34.2    20.4
... 8.4     19.0    31.4    48.7    61.6    68.1    72.2    70.6    62.5    52.7    36.7    23.8
... 11.2    20.0    29.6    47.7    55.8    73.2    68.0    67.1    64.9    57.1    37.6    27.7
... 13.4    17.2    30.8    43.7    62.3    66.4    70.2    71.6    62.1    46.0    32.7    17.3
... 22.5    25.7    42.3    45.2    55.5    68.9    72.3    72.3    62.5    55.6    38.0    20.4
... 17.6    20.5    34.2    49.2    54.8    63.8    74.0    67.1    57.7    50.8    36.8    25.5
... 20.4    19.6    24.6    41.3    61.8    68.5    72.0    71.1    57.3    52.5    40.6    26.2
... '''

>>> sorted(map(float, data.split()), reverse=True)[:3]
[74.0, 73.7, 73.7]
```

If you want to `integer` results

```
>>> temps = sorted(map(float, data.split()), reverse=True)[:3]
>>> map(int, temps)
[74, 73, 73]
```

Comment: `heapq.nlargest` is more efficient for large list.

Comment: @eph Actually It is not large list, `144 items`

Answer (score 8):

You only get the max elements for the first line because you return at the end of the first iteration. You should de-indent the return statement.

Sorting the data and picking the first 3 elements runs in n*log(n).

```
data = [float(v) for v in line.split() for line in file]
sorted(data, reverse=True)[:3]
```

It is perfectly fine for 144 elements.
You can also get the answer in linear time using a heapq

```
import heapq
heapq.nlargest(3, data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with a file, as a cast and numpythonic approach you can load the file as an array and then sort the array and get the last 3 item :

```
import numpy as np
with open('filename') as f:
    array = np.genfromtxt(f).ravel()
    array.sort()

print array[-3:]
[ 73.7  73.7  74. ]
```